# XML Only Displays Background Color With XSL Stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I created 2 files: book.xml and book.xsl. I am trying to open the xml file and display the xsl information. However, only the background color shows, and no other text.

For my class assignment, all I need to do is be able to show that I can transfer XML to another type of file (like XHTML).

I used Firefox and Internet Explorer, and it only shows the background color. Chrome does not show anything at all.

I am using Windows 7 on PC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the codes I typed so far:

XML

```
<!-- book.xml file -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="book.xsl" ?>

<bookstore>
    <h1>List of Books for Sale</h1>
    <li>
    <book>
        <title>Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone</title>
        <author>Author: J.K. Rowling</author>
        <year>Publish Year: 1997</year>
        <price>Price: $29.95 USD</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>Hunger Games</title>
        <author>Author: Suzanne Collins</author>
        <year>Publish Year: 2008</year>
        <price>Price: $39.95 USD</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title>Game of Thrones</title>
        <author>Author: George R.R. Martin</author>
        <year>Publish Year: 1996</year>
        <price>Price: $16.95 USD</price>
    </book>
    </li>
</bookstore>
```

XSLT

```
<!-- book.xsl' file -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- Transfer this HTML to XHTML for display -->

<xsl:template match="/">

    <html> 
        <head> 
            <title> List of Books For Sale </title> 
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:ivory">

            <!-- This is the template logic for the book elements 
            when several nodes match an XPath expression. -->

            <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="author" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="year" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="price" />
            </xsl:for-each>

        </body>
    </html>

    </xsl:template>


    <!-- templates for the name and author elements--> 

        <xsl:template match="title">
            <div style="display:list-item; color:black; margin-left:20pt;">
                <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="author">
            <div style="display:list-item; color:black; margin-left:20pt;">
                <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
            </div>
        </xsl:template>


            <xsl:template match="year">
                <div style="display:list-item; color:black; margin-left:20pt;">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </div>
            </xsl:template>


            <xsl:template match="price">
                <div style="display:list-item; color:black; margin-left:20pt;">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </div>
            </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your XML, the `book` element is nested within an `li` element, but you have not accounted for that in the XPath expression you use to select `book` elements.

Instead of doing this...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book">
```

You just need to do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="bookstore/li/book">
```

Also note that your input XML is not well-formed in your question, as you are missing the closing `</bookstore>` tag.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It worked. I appreciate the help, Tim! :D

Comment: I forgot to put the end tag </bookstore> here, but I had it in my document. Just adding the <bookstore/li/book> worked. :)